# Cadence simulation graph versus time

Tags: timer, cadence, graph, plot

please do not know if there is a functionality in CADENCE in the graphs show differences in the times between them (make an average of two values). Regarding the delay of two waves [Automatically in the graph or table]. Example is in the image.

[image]

Comment: There is a delay function which measures the time between edges